# Migrate + Access $row values in a custom progress plugin

Tags: migrations

I use migrate/migrate_plus modules fo import datas from xml file.
I want create a custom progress plugin to alter a value. I want to use a second value from the row to alter my first value.
In my custom module, and inside my "transform function" I tried to call the $row values without sucess.

here is my code:

```
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateException;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigratePluginManager;
use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "convert_my_data",
 * )
 */
class ConvertMyData extends ProcessPluginBase {

/**
 * The row from the source to process.
 *
 * @var \Drupal\migrate\Row
 */
protected $row;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {

dpm($row)
...
```

But, dpm($row) don't render any results/datas. Is there a solution to call the other datas of the current row?

Thanks for your help.